# Box API always returns invalid grant_type parameter on obtaining access token

Tags: box-api

I'm writing my own Box SDK for WP8 to make the most out of Tasks. I am having trouble obtaining an access token. I always get this as a return:

```
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Invalid grant_type parameter or parameter missing"}
```

The code (all in C#) I'm using is:

```
    internal const String TokenURL = "https://api.box.com/oauth2/token";

CloudHttpAsync.DownloadResponceStreamAsync
(
    CloudHttpAsync.PostAsync
    (
        TokenURL,
        new MemoryStream
        (
            UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes
            (
                HttpUtility.UrlEncode
                (
                    String.Format
                    (
                        "grant_type=authorization_code&code={0}&client_id={1}&client_secret={2}&redirect_uri={3}",
                        Code,
                        ClientID,
                        ClientSecret,
                        RedirectURI
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
        null,
        null
    ),
    null
).ContinueWith((AsyncStream) =>
    {
        try
        {
            if (AsyncStream.Exception != null)
            {
                TaskSource.TrySetException(AsyncStream.Exception.InnerExceptions);
                return;
            }

            String Result = "";
            using (StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(AsyncStream.Result))
            {
                Result = Reader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            BoxAuthToken Token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<BoxAuthToken>(Result);
            TaskSource.TrySetResult(Token);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            TaskSource.TrySetException(e);
        }
    });
```

and

```
    public static Task<HttpWebResponse> PostAsync(String URL, Stream UploadData, IRequestSigner Signer, IProgress<NetworkProgress> Progress)
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<HttpWebResponse> TaskSource = new TaskCompletionSource<HttpWebResponse>();

        HttpWebRequest Request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(URL);
        Request.Method = "POST";

        if (Signer != null)
        {
            Signer.Sign(Request).ContinueWith((o) =>
            {
                if (o.Exception != null)
                {
                    TaskSource.TrySetException(o.Exception.InnerExceptions);
                    return;
                }

                UploadDataAsync(Request, UploadData, Progress).ContinueWith((AsyncRequest) =>
                {
                    if (AsyncRequest.Exception != null)
                    {
                        TaskSource.TrySetException(AsyncRequest.Exception.InnerExceptions);
                        return;
                    }

                    GetResponceAsync(Request).ContinueWith((AsyncResponce) =>
                    {
                        if (AsyncResponce.Exception != null)
                        {
                            TaskSource.TrySetException(AsyncResponce.Exception.InnerExceptions);
                            return;
                        }

                        TaskSource.TrySetResult(AsyncResponce.Result);
                    });
                });
            });
        }
        else
        {
            UploadDataAsync(Request, UploadData, Progress).ContinueWith((AsyncRequest) =>
            {
                if (AsyncRequest.Exception != null)
                {
                    TaskSource.TrySetException(AsyncRequest.Exception.InnerExceptions);
                    return;
                }

                GetResponceAsync(Request).ContinueWith((AsyncResponce) =>
                {
                    if (AsyncResponce.Exception != null)
                    {
                        TaskSource.TrySetException(AsyncResponce.Exception.InnerExceptions);
                        return;
                    }

                    TaskSource.TrySetResult(AsyncResponce.Result);
                });
            });
        }

        return TaskSource.Task;
    }

    internal static Task<HttpWebRequest> UploadDataAsync(HttpWebRequest Request, Stream Data, IProgress<NetworkProgress> Progress)
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<HttpWebRequest> TaskSource = new TaskCompletionSource<HttpWebRequest>();

        if (Data.Length != 0)
        {
            Request.ContentLength = Data.Length;
            Request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false;

            Request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback((IAR) =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        using (Stream UploadStream = Request.EndGetRequestStream(IAR))
                        {
                            Int64 Upload = 0;
                            Int64 TotalUploaded = 0;
                            Int64 Total = Data.Length;
                            Byte[] Buffer = new Byte[4096];

                            while (TotalUploaded < Total)
                            {
                                Upload = Data.Read(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length);
                                TotalUploaded += Upload;
                                UploadStream.Write(Buffer, 0, (Int32)Upload);

                                if (Progress != null)
                                {
                                    Progress.Report(new NetworkProgress()
                                    {
                                        Operation = NetworkOperation.Uploading,
                                        TotalBytes = Total,
                                        BytesProcessed = TotalUploaded
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        TaskSource.TrySetResult(Request);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        TaskSource.TrySetException(e);
                    }
                }),
                null);
        }
        else
        {
            TaskSource.TrySetResult(Request);
        }

        return TaskSource.Task;
    }

    internal static Task<HttpWebResponse> GetResponceAsync(HttpWebRequest Request)
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<HttpWebResponse> TaskSource = new TaskCompletionSource<HttpWebResponse>();

        Request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback((IAR) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    HttpWebResponse Responce = (HttpWebResponse)Request.EndGetResponse(IAR);
                    TaskSource.TrySetResult(Responce);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    if (e is WebException && (e as WebException).Response.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        TaskSource.TrySetResult((HttpWebResponse)(e as WebException).Response);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        TaskSource.TrySetException(e);
                    }
                }
            }),
            null);

        return TaskSource.Task;
    }

    public static Task<StreamAndLength> GetResponceStreamAsync(Task<HttpWebResponse> Task)
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<StreamAndLength> TaskSource = new TaskCompletionSource<StreamAndLength>();

        Task.ContinueWith((AsyncHWR) =>
            {
                if (AsyncHWR.Exception != null)
                {
                    TaskSource.TrySetException(AsyncHWR.Exception.InnerExceptions);
                    return;
                }

                HttpWebResponse Responce = AsyncHWR.Result;
                TaskSource.TrySetResult( new StreamAndLength() { Stream = Responce.GetResponseStream(), Length = Responce.ContentLength });
            });

        return TaskSource.Task;
    }

    public static Task<MemoryStream> DownloadResponceStreamAsync(Task<HttpWebResponse> Task, IProgress<NetworkProgress> Progress)
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<MemoryStream> TaskSource = new TaskCompletionSource<MemoryStream>();

        GetResponceStreamAsync(Task).ContinueWith((AsyncStream) =>
            {
                if (AsyncStream.Exception != null)
                {
                    TaskSource.TrySetException(AsyncStream.Exception.InnerExceptions);
                    return;
                }

                MemoryStream MemStream = new MemoryStream();
                MemStream.SetLength(AsyncStream.Result.Length);

                Int64 CurrentRead = 0;
                Int64 TotalRead = 0;
                Int64 Total = AsyncStream.Result.Length;
                Byte[] Buffer = new Byte[4096];

                using (Stream DownloadStream = AsyncStream.Result.Stream)
                while (TotalRead < Total)
                {
                    CurrentRead = DownloadStream.Read(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length);
                    MemStream.Write(Buffer, 0, (Int32)CurrentRead);
                    TotalRead += CurrentRead;

                    if (Progress != null)
                    {
                        Progress.Report(new NetworkProgress()
                        {
                            Operation = NetworkOperation.Downloading,
                            TotalBytes = Total,
                            BytesProcessed = TotalRead
                        });
                    }
                }

                MemStream.Position = 0;
                TaskSource.TrySetResult(MemStream);
            });

        return TaskSource.Task;
    }

    internal class StreamAndLength
    {
        public Stream Stream { get; set; }
        public Int64 Length { get; set; }
    }
```

Sorry there is a lot of code, I like to write generically :)

Edit: Raw Responces (ClientID & Client Secret removed)

When URL encoding each value:

```
POST https://api.box.com/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 196
Accept-Encoding: identity
User-Agent: NativeHost
Host: api.box.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache

grant_type=authorization_code&code=JknaLbfT6lAXmey3FLYrp9eg1jMbpFuQ&client_id=[subbed]&client_secret=[subbed]&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fCloudBoxWP8
```

Return:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 01 Mar 2013 07:35:22 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: box_visitor_id=51305a3a187f34.52738262; expires=Sat, 01-Mar-2014 07:35:22 GMT; path=/; domain=.box.com
Set-Cookie: country_code=US; expires=Tue, 30-Apr-2013 07:35:22 GMT; path=/
Cache-Control: no-store
Content-Length: 99

{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Invalid grant_type parameter or parameter missing"}
```

When URL encode the entire string:

```
POST https://api.box.com/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 214
Accept-Encoding: identity
User-Agent: NativeHost
Host: api.box.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache

grant_type%3dauthorization_code%26code%3d3ikruv5elfdw3fOP55aMDSX7ybLqBFlA%26client_id%3d[subbed]%26client_secret%3d[subbed]%26redirect_uri%3dhttps%3a%2f%2fCloudBoxWP8
```

Return

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 01 Mar 2013 07:46:03 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: box_visitor_id=51305cbb339de4.03221876; expires=Sat, 01-Mar-2014 07:46:03 GMT; path=/; domain=.box.com
Set-Cookie: country_code=US; expires=Tue, 30-Apr-2013 07:46:03 GMT; path=/
Cache-Control: no-store
Content-Length: 99

{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Invalid grant_type parameter or parameter missing"}
```

No URL encoding:

```
POST https://api.box.com/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 190
Accept-Encoding: identity
User-Agent: NativeHost
Host: api.box.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Cache-Control: no-cache

grant_type=authorization_code&code=2wgIzfqhvIgRtVIp2ZvqZ9X8R5u0QNaf&client_id=[subbed]&client_secret=[subbed]&redirect_uri=https://CloudBoxWP8
```

Return:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 01 Mar 2013 07:50:31 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: box_visitor_id=51305dc751d7f5.67064854; expires=Sat, 01-Mar-2014 07:50:31 GMT; path=/; domain=.box.com
Set-Cookie: country_code=US; expires=Tue, 30-Apr-2013 07:50:31 GMT; path=/
Cache-Control: no-store
Content-Length: 99

{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Invalid grant_type parameter or parameter missing"}
```

Comment: Tom, can you post a [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) trace of the HTTP request that's being sent to Box?

Comment: Also, are you URL encoding the redirect uri?

Comment: Just tried only URL encoding the redirect address to the same result. Now using fiddler I have tried using it to send the POST, using what should be a valid Request body it also returns the no grant_type error. Trying again I made a POST request to https://api.box.com/oauth2/token with request body "grant_type=authorization_code" and still I get the no grant_type error!

Comment: Can you post the raw request and response data (with any secret info stubbed out)?

Comment: Hi Tom, how are you doing with this?  Do you need any more help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not listed anywhere on the Box API documentation, but the request for retrieving the access token requires the header `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

I was also stuck on this part for a while until I found the answer on StackOverflow. I forget the link to it though.

Answer (score 0):

The request/response would be helpful.  It looks like you are UrlEncoding the entire query string instead of just each value.  Which would be submitted to us as:
grant_type%3Dauthorization_code%26code%3Dxyz%26client_id%3Dxyz%26client_secret%3Dxyz%26redirect_uri%3Dxyz

Instead of:
grant_type=authorization_code&code=xyz&client_id=xyz&client_secret=xyz&redirect_uri=xyz

Comment: Just attempted that to not effect. I've posted the Raw request & response data so you can see yourself

Answer (score 0):

I think that including the `redirect_uri` in your request body could be complicating things, particularly because it looks to be set to an invalid value (`https://CloudBoxWP8`)  You might resolve this by setting your app to handle a custom protocol (`cloudboxwp8://`) and pre-configuring Box to redirect to that when the token is granted.

1. [Register a custom protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_URIassociations) for your WP8 app.  For example, `cloudboxwp8`.
2. Augment your WP8 app to handle a request for some endpoint on that protocol.  For example, `cloudboxwp8://tokengranted`.  Implement your token handling logic here.
3. Edit your Box application and browse to the OAuth2 paramters section (via [Manage a Box Application](https://www.box.com/developers/services) => Edit Application)
4. In the `redirect_uri` field, set the value to the custom protocol and endpoint from step 2. Save your changes.
5. Remove the `redirect_uri` from your request body and try your request again.

Comment: I've been a little busy the last few days, and will be until the weekend. I will try this then. Just to point out, I can perform the login part fine through a WebBrowser Control which pops up within the app (so the library I'm writing is completely self contained), this method has worked fine with other OAuth implementations such as with Dropbox. Sorry for the late reply!

Answer (score 0):

in Windows phone 8.1 WinRT

```
Dictionary<string, string> contentList = new Dictionary<string, string>();

contentList.Add("code", code);
contentList.Add("client_id", client_id);
contentList.Add("client_secret", clientSecret);
contentList.Add("redirect_uri", redirectUri);
contentList.Add("grant_type", "authorization_code");

FormUrlEncodedContent content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(contentList);

var response = await client.PostAsync(baseURL, content);
YouTubeAutenticationResponse res =       JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YouTubeAutenticationResponse>(await     response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

public class YouTubeAutenticationResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("access_token")]
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("token_type")]
    public string TokenType { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("expires_in")]
    public string ExpiresIn { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("refresh_token")]
    public string RefreshToken { get; set; }
}
```