# Box oauth2: Invalid grant_type parameter or parameter missing

Tags: oauth-2.0, box-api

I don't know what I do wrong, but everytime I tried to obtain the token (after user authentication of course), the result is always Invalid grant_type parameter or parameter missing

Possibly related to [Box API always returns invalid grant_type parameter on obtaining access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15111710/box-api-always-returns-invalid-grant-type-parameter-on-obtaining-access-token)

Here is my fiddler result:

```
POST https://api.box.com/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: api.box.com
Content-Length: 157
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

grant_type=authorization_code&code=nnqtYcoik7cjtHQYyn3Af8uk4LG3rYYh&client_id=[myclientId]&client_secret=[mysecret]
```

Result:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: nginx
Date: Thu, 07 Mar 2013 11:18:36 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: box_visitor_id=5138778bf12a01.27393131; expires=Fri, 07-Mar-2014 11:18:35 GMT; path=/; domain=.box.com
Set-Cookie: country_code=US; expires=Mon, 06-May-2013 11:18:36 GMT; path=/
Cache-Control: no-store
Content-Length: 99

{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Invalid grant_type parameter or parameter missing"}
```

Even following the curl example gives the same error. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: tried with additional redirect_uri params but still the same error

```
POST https://api.box.com/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Host: api.box.com
Content-Length: 187
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

grant_type=authorization_code&code=R3JxS7UPm8Gjc0y7YLj9qxifdzBYzLOZ&client_id=*****&client_secret=*****&redirect_uri=http://localhost
```

Result:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 09 Mar 2013 00:46:38 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: box_visitor_id=513a866ec5cfe0.48604831; expires=Sun, 09-Mar-2014 00:46:38 GMT; path=/; domain=.box.com
Set-Cookie: country_code=US; expires=Wed, 08-May-2013 00:46:38 GMT; path=/
Cache-Control: no-store
Content-Length: 99

{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Invalid grant_type parameter or parameter missing"}
```

Comment: Check John Hoerr reply: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15437525/box-api-oauth2-acces-token-request-error-invalid-grant-type-parameter-or-parame

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Looks like Box requires a correct `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request header in addition to properly URL encoding the parameters. The same seems to apply to refresh and revoke requests.

Also, per [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1.3), the `redirect_uri` is only

> REQUIRED, if the "redirect_uri" parameter was included in the authorization request
> as described in Section 4.1.1, and their values MUST be identical.

Comment: Thank you. The root issue is not having a correct content-type. In the end I removed the redirect_uri from the form request

Comment: I was wondering about that redirect!  Some apps don't need a redirect, like android, so it was a mystery why one was needed on the request.  Thank you!

Comment: I had a space at the end of my grant_type by accident. Removed it and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

I was facing a similar issue.

- The problem is not with Content-Type.
- The issue is with the lifecycle of code you receive.

One key aspect not mentioned in most places is that the code you get on redirect lasts only **30 seconds**.

To get the access token and refresh token, you have to make the post request in 30 seconds or less.

If you fail to do that, you get the stated error. I found the info [here](https://youtu.be/ha26tN8amI0?t=200).

Below code worked for me. Keep in mind, the 30-second rule.

```
import requests

url = 'https://api.box.com/oauth2/token'

data = [
    ('grant_type', 'authorization_code'),
    ('client_id', 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID'),
    ('client_secret', 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET'),
    ('code', 'XXXXXX'),
]

response = requests.post(url, data=data)

print(response.content)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks man, I was thinking that API I was using was broken, but the problem was this 30 seconds

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! I couldn't fix the issue with even a normal request via burp (I'm still a novice on how to do them right) but this solved the problem for me

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the redirect URI parameter. Try:

```
POST https://api.box.com/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: api.box.com
Content-Length: 157
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

grant_type=authorization_code&code=nnqtYcoik7cjtHQYyn3Af8uk4LG3rYYh&client_id=[myclientId]&client_secret=[mysecret]&redirect_uri=[your-redirect-uri]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also face same issue implementing oauth2. I have add `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. When I add `content-type` my issue solved.

Check and add valid `content-type`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure who might need this in the future but be sure you're sending a POST request to get the access token and not trying to retrieve it by using GET or if you're testing- pasting in the address bar won't work, you need to send a POST request with the data in the BODY and not as query parameter.

Also the code usually lasts for a few seconds, so you need to use it as soon as its sent back.

Answer (score 0):

After trying all the solutions, if the error is still the same, then try this middleware in your `server/app/index`:

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?